# How to play a live video in the browser?

Tags: http-live-streaming, live-streaming

I need to get live video from a device. I have to play the video on the browser. live video can be received as RTP or UDP.

Since there is no support for VLC, I published the video by getting it via RTP with FFMPEG and creating a web server with Nginx.
But later I realized that it is recording video tracks to disk. This is a situation I don't want.

Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Is there anyone who can help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with RTP or UDP, no, there is no way. You must use WebRTC, or an HTTP based method like HLS or DASH.

Comment: I converted the video to RTMP using FFMPEG and Nginx. I can show it in web browser using HLS.js

It is saving to HDD when I use the following command.

Can I prevent this? I don't want it to save to HDD.

Comment: ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:5000 -vcodec libx264 -vprofile baseline -acodec aac -strict -2 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/show/stream

Comment: When the codec I understand is changed, it saves the video to HDD. I think I prevented it from recording like this. But I don't know how to play from the web browser.                                                            
                         ffmpeg -i udp://127.0.0.1:5000 -strict -2 -max_muxing_queue_size 1024 -f flv rtmp://127.0.0.1/show/stream

Comment: New questions should go in new posts. Not in comments.

Comment: Thank you for the information. New question as it may be needed : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63796892/ffmpeg-delete-unused-files-or-streaming-without-saving-files